# How can NSString write to a file when I have a FILE handle open for reading?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io

I have a sample iOS app in which I am trying to measure the time taken by the various file writing alternatives. While measuring the time, I noticed that NSString's writeToFile method write to the file even when I have a file handle for read on the same file that has been obtained by using fopen().

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's easy. writeToFile creates a new file with the same name. Your file handle refers to the old file. The old file will disappear when you close the file handle; it's name already disappeared when writeToFile created a new file.

Comment: But how can a file be written to when I already have a (FILE *) open for write to the same file? Based on what I looked up, writeToFile is supposed to create a temporary file, write to that and replace the actual file when all handles to it are closed. But when I ran the app while keeping the finder window open, I noticed that the file is being written to as soon as the line executes while another thread already has a handle open for write.

Comment: Also, if it is indeed the case that you mentioned, does that mean that if I try to read in the same fashion while writeToFile is writing to it, I will get the old data instead of the new one?